# Subject after "but"

Tags: grammar

> "I love fruits *but* ***I am*** allergic to strawberries"
>
> "They have bought a house in Manchester *but* ***they*** still haven't sold their house in London"

Does it really need to use `"I am"` & `"they"` after `"but"` in the above examples?

Can we leave the `"I am"` and `"they"` in the above examples and say,

> "I love fruits but allergic to strawberries"
>
> "They have bought a house in Manchester but still haven't sold their house in London"

I want to know the grammar rules behind this, that when we can leave the subject or subject+verb after `"but"`.

This doubt really came to my mind when I was writing something like this

> "I don't sleep at night but in the morning"

I left the words `"I sleep"` after `"but"` in the above example.

Should that be -

> "I don't sleep at night *but* ***I sleep*** in the morning"

But it looks redundant to me.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid repeating the Subject after But.

Coordinating conjunctions (such as 'But', 'And') are defined as:
Conjunctions placed between words, phrases, clauses, or sentences of equal rank.

When the Subject in a sentence is same for two verbs, then, using 'But' would make a Compound Verb, and its fine not to repeat the subject in such cases.

Therefore, your sentence can be written as:

> I don't sleep at night but in the morning.

(Edit- answered the ques asked in the comment section):

Since the verb is one and the same it can be omitted alongwith the subject (after using the coordinating conjunction).

But in cases where the verb is different, it **cannot** be omitted. For example:

> I *came* late but was *excused*.

For further insight, you can have a look at this:
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233741/do-i-have-to-repeat-the-same-subject-after-and-when-introducing-a-new-verb

The below mentioned link would give you the understanding of when to use a Comma before But, in such cases:
https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma/ (13th Point)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and links. That really helped me. But I have one more question, should that be *"I don't sleep at night, but ***sleep*** in the morning"* or *"I don't sleep at night, but in the morning"*. And also, why did you use comma before the "but"? To me "in the morning" is a dependent clause and you shouldn't use comma before *"but"*, right?

Comment: Found this question valid enough, so have included it in the main answer itself.

Comment: I may confess this that 'commas' are something which confuse me. :p You were right about not inserting a comma there. Thanks for correcting. :p

Comment: What about this question - should that be *"I don't sleep at night, but ***sleep*** in the morning"* or *"I don't sleep at night, but in the morning"*. I'm little confused here. As you mentioned in your answer, the verb "sleep" is same in both the first and second phrase, so I can leave the second one and say "but in the morning" right?

Comment: Ya, you can omit the verb if its same. Sentence can be written as: I dont sleep at night but in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

You don't add a comma before but in "I don't sleep at night but in the morning".
But you should add a comma before but in "I don't sleep at night, but I sleep in the morning." The first one is a Compound Verb, and the second one is a clause. You need the comma before coordinating conjunctions + clause. You should not use a comma for the compound verb.

"I don't sleep at night but in the morning" is better than "I don't sleep at night, but I sleep in the morning." Because the former is more concise.