# When to omit pronoun after "but"?

Tags: grammar

I have the two sentences:

**Original sentences:**

"I baked an apple pie, but I forgot to put cinnamon in it."

"Sonia speaks English but does not write it."

My questions:

1. Can I write: I baked an apple pie, but forgot to put cinnamon in it.
   (I removed "I" after "but")? Is it correct?
2. Is is it correct to write: "Sonia speaks English but she does not write it."?
3. What is the rule to omit pronoun after "but"? Please explain this
   using the original sentences.

Related: 
[Is it always necessary to repeat the pronoun before each verb?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/310/is-it-always-necessary-to-repeat-the-pronoun-before-each-verb)

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/153977/47419

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I baked an apple pie, but forgot to put cinnamon in it.
>   I baked an apple pie, but **I** forgot to put cinnamon in it.
>
> Sonia speaks English but does not write it.
>   Sonia speaks English but **she** does not write it.

Both forms of your two sentences are equivalent in meaning.  The additional pronoun can be left out if there is no ambiguity in the understanding

> Susan and I baked an apple pie, but forgot to put cinnamon in it.

is understood as

> *Susan and I baked an apple pie, but* ***we*** *forgot to put cinnamon in it*.

and is different than

> Susan and I baked an apple pie, but **she** forgot to put cinnamon in it.
>   Susan and I baked an apple pie, but **I** forgot to put cinnamon in it.

Since your examples only have a single subject being referred to, there is no ambiguity.